# javafx: label value updates cause error when massively setting values

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

I wrote a java program with javafx ui to show a live counter of transactions,
many threads needs to write a updated value into a single label,I did like this:

1-"SOME_NUMBER" is an integer variable in the main class(not the fx controller Class itself,let's consider its name "MainClass") that defines this way:

```
public static Integer SOME_NUMBER;
```

2-Many Threads Update the value of "SOME_NUMBER" this way:

```
synchronized(SOME_NUMBER){
    MainClass.SOME_NUMBER--;
}
synchronized(SOME_NUMBER){
    MainClass.SOME_NUMBER++;
}
```

3-Finally the result shows from other classes this way:

```
label.setText(String.valueOf(SOME_NUMBER));
```

the numbers should be update at every second so i don't want to use a `Task` to update my View in specific intervals,And Also don't want to use `Platform.runLater` because when you have about 5-20 transactions per second it shows them with considerable delay...
so i want a safe way to implement such a thing to satisfy my needs,because my current implementation causes to errors like this which i remove the ui update all of that goes away:

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.createLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getYRendering(Unknown Source)
```

is there any chance to use a observable value or something like that?

Comment: You could use two [`DoubleProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html)s (one in the GUI, one in your logic), bind them bidirectionally and set the value of this `DoubleProperty` within your production code.

Comment: @Turing85
Can you show me an example/code snippet of that?

Comment: You can find a tutorial explaining JavaFX Properties and Bindings [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).

Comment: I recommend not binding GUI components to a property whose value is modified off of the JavaFX application thread.  Such as strategy may cause your program to inconsistently fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), just copy and paste with slight modifications to use the same technique as Task uses (the following code is just a copy and paste from the Task source).

If you know that your value is an Integer, then you may wish to use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) rather than an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

The code will provide you with a message property, whose value you can attempt to update from any thread (via the `updateMessage` API), though an update will only occur when the JavaFX application thread is ready to process it.  You can also observe the property for changes and safely bind JavaFX UI components to the property knowing that the property itself has only even been updated on the JavaFX application thread.

```
/**
 * Used to send message updates in a thread-safe manner from the subclass
 * to the FX application thread. AtomicReference is used so as to coalesce
 * updates such that we don't flood the event queue.
 */
private AtomicReference<String> messageUpdate = new AtomicReference<>();

private final StringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "message", "");
@Override public final String getMessage() { checkThread(); return message.get(); }
@Override public final ReadOnlyStringProperty messageProperty() { checkThread(); return message; }

/**
 * Updates the <code>message</code> property. Calls to updateMessage
 * are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread, so calls
 * to updateMessage, even from the FX Application thread, may not
 * necessarily result in immediate updates to this property, and
 * intermediate message values may be coalesced to save on event
 * notifications.
 * <p>
 *     <em>This method is safe to be called from any thread.</em>
 * </p>
 *
 * @param message the new message
 */
protected void updateMessage(String message) {
    if (isFxApplicationThread()) {
        this.message.set(message);
    } else {
        // As with the workDone, it might be that the background thread
        // will update this message quite frequently, and we need
        // to throttle the updates so as not to completely clobber
        // the event dispatching system.
        if (messageUpdate.getAndSet(message) == null) {
            runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    final String message = messageUpdate.getAndSet(null);
                    Task.this.message.set(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void checkThread() {
    if (started && !isFxApplicationThread()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Task must only be used from the FX Application Thread");
    }
}
```